# How to change datacontext at runtime with Mvvm

Tags: wpf

I have a graph that I want to change some ViewModel property so the whole graph would change accordingly.

The only property that I want to change here is "year", I tried to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged so the binding will cause the graph to change automatically, but it didn't work.

This is the model:

```
 public class Model
{

    public double rate { get; set; }

    public string date { get; set; }

}
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _year;

    public string Year { get { return _year; } set { _year = value;UpdateData(); OnPropertyChanged("Year"); } }

    public ViewModel()
    {
      _year = "2017";
      UpdateData();

    }

    public void UpdateData()
    {
      int i,j;//Indexs that holds actuall api retrived values
        string cR, urlContents;// cR- current rate in string format, urlContents - the whole Api retrived data
        string c;//For api syntx, add 0 or not, depends on the current date syntax

        this.CurrenciesHis = new ObservableCollection<Model>();//Model objects collection

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();



        for (int l = 1; l < 13; l++)
        {
            if (l < 10)
                c = "0";
            else
                c = "";

            urlContents = client.GetStringAsync("http://data.fixer.io/api/"+(_year)+"-"+ c + l + "-01?access_key=&base=USD&symbols=EUR&format=1").Result;


            i = urlContents.IndexOf("EUR");//Finds the desired value from api recived data
            j = urlContents.IndexOf("}");

            cR = urlContents.Substring(i + 5, (j - 2) - (i + 5));

            CurrenciesHis.Add(new Model() { rate = Convert.ToDouble(cR), date = "01/" + l.ToString() });
        }



     }

    public ObservableCollection<Model> CurrenciesHis { get; set; }

    #region "INotifyPropertyChanged members" 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 



    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

This is the View that based on third party control (I deleted alot of XAML and used bold letters to mark where is the actuall binding located):

```
<layout:SampleLayoutWindow x:Class="AreaChart.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.WPF"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PL" 
    xmlns:layout="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Windows.SampleLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.Chart.Wpf.SampleLayout"
    UserOptionsVisibility="Collapsed"                   
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="643.287" Width="1250.5"        
    Title="2017">
<Grid>



    <Grid.Resources>

      ...........................................



        <chart:AreaSeries x:Name="AreaSeries" EnableAnimation="True"
                          **XBindingPath="date" 
                          Label="Favourite"
                          YBindingPath="rate" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding CurrenciesHis}"** 
                          ShowTooltip="True" >
            <chart:AreaSeries.AdornmentsInfo>
                <chart:ChartAdornmentInfo AdornmentsPosition="Bottom"  
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          ShowLabel="True">
                    <chart:ChartAdornmentInfo.LabelTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        ....................................



    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="28,231,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="Text1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Text="{Binding Year, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

</Grid>
```

This is the code behaind and the event of the Textbox that I want to change with it's help that year property of the viewmodel:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : SampleLayoutWindow
{

    PL.ViewModel newInstance;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        newInstance = new PL.ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = newInstance;
    }



  }
```

What I understand is that from this point the mechanism of WPFwill change the values on the chart using the binding and the "notification" of INotifyPropertyChanged but it doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`year` should be a private field, but it is public. You're setting the value of the field, which naturally does not execute any of the code in the setter for the property.

Make `year` and all of your backing fields private, and rename all of your private fields with a leading underscore (for example, `year` should be renamed to `_year`) to prevent accidents like this.

And make it a policy in your viewmodel code always to set the *property*, never the field, except of course inside the actual property setter for that field.

Also, use bindings to set viewmodel properties from UI. Don't do it in codebehind. Get rid of that textchanged handler.

```
<TextBox 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="30" 
    Margin="28,231,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="76" 
    Text="{Binding Year, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    />
```

Finally, it seems that you intended for changes to `Year` to have some effect on the contents of `CurrenciesHis`, but there's no mechanism for that in your code, and no explanation of what you want to have happen or how you expect it to happen.

---

And here's an updated version of your viewmodel.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        //  DO NOT, DO NOT EVER, DO NOT, SERIOUSLY, EVER, EVER, EVER UPDATE A 
        //  PROPERTY'S BACKING FIELD OUTSIDE THE PROPERTY'S SETTER. 
        Year = DateTime.Now.Year - 1;

        UpdateCurrencies();
    }

    protected void UpdateCurrencies()
    {
        //  Indexs that holds actuall api retrived values
        int i, j;
        //  cR- current rate in string format, urlContents - the whole Api retrived data
        string cR, urlContents;
        //  For api syntx, add 0 or not, depends on the current date syntax
        string c;

        CurrenciesHis = new ObservableCollection<Model>();//Model objects collection

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        for (int l = 1; l < 13; l++)
        {
            if (l < 10)
                c = "0";
            else
                c = "";

            //  Use the public property Year, not the field _year
            var url = "http://data.fixer.io/api/" + Year + "-" + c + l + "-01?access_key=&base=USD&symbols=EUR&format=1";
            urlContents = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
            i = urlContents.IndexOf("EUR");//Finds the desired value from api recived data
            j = urlContents.IndexOf("}");

            cR = urlContents.Substring(i + 5, (j - 2) - (i + 5));

            CurrenciesHis.Add(new Model() { rate = Convert.ToDouble(cR), date = "01/" + l.ToString() });
        }

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrenciesHis));
    }

    //  Year is an integer, so make it an integer. The binding will work fine, 
    //  and it'll prevent the user from typing "lol". 
    private int _year;
    public int Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
        set
        {
            if (_year != value)
            {
                _year = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Year));
                UpdateCurrencies();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model> CurrenciesHis { get; private set; }

    //  -----------------------------------------------------
    //  YearsList property for ComboBox

    //  30 years, starting 30 years ago. 
    //  You could make this IEnumerable<int> or ReadOnlyCollection<int> if you 
    //  want something other than the ComboBox to use it. The ComboBox doesn't care.
    //  Year MUST be an int for the binding to SelectedItem (see below) to work, 
    //  not a string. 
    public System.Collections.IEnumerable YearsList 
            => Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 30, 30).ToList().AsReadOnly();

}
```

XAML for YearsList combobox (which I prefer to the text box btw):

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding YearsList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Year}"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you,you right. I updated the ViewModel code.Right now the content of the _year property does presents on the textbox when the window loads (the intial value that was defined in the ViewModel) but the graph still doesn't respond to changes in the textbox.

Comment: @JohnMerc 1) What _year property? That should be the name of the private field. 2) What code did YOU write that updates the collection when Year changes? Please show me how your code does that.

Comment: I meant Year, as for the second question I was naive enough to think that it will work by it's own since I used "INotifyPropertyChanged", how should I update the collection when Year changes ?

Comment: @JohnMerc Take all the code that updates the collection in your viewmodel constructor, and put it in a separate method. Name it UpdateData() or something. Call UpdateData() in your viewmodel constrictor and also call it in the setter for Year.

Comment: I updated the viewmodel in the question accordingly but I still can't see that the TextBox effects the binding in the graph

Comment: @JohnMerc No, you didn't update accordingly. You ignored several important things I told you to do. Please fix your code so you do *everything* I told you to do.

Comment: What did I ignored ? I read your comment for the second time and I think I checked everything , what did I miss ?

Comment: @JohnMerc If you're unable to compare the code in my answer to that in your question, I can't help you. It is not possible for me to edit the code in your project for you, and I wouldn't if I could.

Comment: Why won't you tell me what did I ignored ?.. In the ViewModel I changed _year to private, I took all the code from the constructor and put in UpdateData(), then I called that function from the constructor, I also called that function from set of Year.then I erased the the text box event from the code behind in the view and added "Text="{Binding Year, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" in the TextBox XAML..

Comment: @JohnMerc I checked your code a minute ago and thought I still saw the event handler there. I definitely see the binding now though. Put a breakpoint in the setter for `Year` and make sure that gets hit when you type in the year box. If it doesn't, change the binding as follows: `{Binding Year, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}` and look at the Output pane in VS at runtime to see debugging info about the binding (don't leave that there permanently, it eats a lot of cycles, but it's great for diagnosis)

Comment: Thanks, the last version that you edited for the view model worked.. How would you bind a combobox in a similar manner ?

Comment: @JohnMerc You’d expose a `ReadOnlyCollection<int>` property for the YearsList and bind that to ItemsSource on the combo. Then you’d bind year to SelectedItem on the combo.

Comment: @JohnMerc See update at end of viewmodel and added XAML at the end of my answer. Note that Year ***MUST be an integer*** for SelectedItem to work with that collection of ints, unless you want to change YearsList to `Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 30, 30).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList().AsReadOnly()`. But int is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Your CurrenciesHis property doesn't implement INPC so WPF doesn't realize that you changed it (UpdateData() has "this.CurrenciesHis = new ObservableCollection();")

Your current property is:

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> CurrenciesHis { get; set; }
```

Should be something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Model> _CurrenciesHis;
public ObservableCollection<Model> CurrenciesHis { get { return _CurrenciesHis; } set { if (_CurrenciesHis != value) { _CurrenciesHis = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrenciesHis"); } } }
```