# How to update DataContext in WPF applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am learning WPF and i've met an obstacle. I have a xaml file with Window:

```
...      
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:LeaguesViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin ="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding Path=HeaderText}"/>
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Leagues}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Country" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Country}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Num of teams" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NumOfTeamsQualifiedToUCL}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=SomeText}" />
    </Grid>
...
```

I would like to change a datacontext in a runtime. How to do it?

Comment: `I would like to change a datacontext` why, you shouldn't have to. You should be updating the properties that are bound to the view through the viewmodel. How are you setting your viewmodel now to that view now?

Comment: MVVM is quite flexible. You have a few options, so consider refining the question further, as demonstrating all solutions would be a bit much. It can be done so keep learning. What you have here is the 'View First approach' and your can either assign the data context in the view (XAML), or you may assign the data context in the code behind. Or you can take a completely different approach with 'ViewModel First'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change datacontext at runtime with Mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008964/how-to-change-datacontext-at-runtime-with-mvvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to how to change the data context of your `Window`, it's pretty easy and straightforward.

Let's suppose you have two `ViewModel`s, `VM1` and `VM2`. Initially you have `VM1` set as the `DataContext` from your `XAML`, and that you want to change it to `VM2` on a button click event. So all you want to do it set data context from code behind, like so:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm2 = new VM2();
    DataContext = vm2;
}
```

But it's a different question *why* you would want to do that. Unless you know for certain that you want to change the `DataContext` of a `View` at runtime, you shouldn't. Typically you bind a `ViewModel` to a `View` and let it be. Any changes are done thought the member variables in that `ViewModel`. You probably want to read up more on this.